# Zend Translate Zend Form!

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, translation

Currently, isEmpty errors throw:

```
    Value is required and can't be empty
```

I'm loading my translator up like this:

```
[translation]

adapter = array
content.english["emailNotUnique"] = "Your user already exists"
content.english["Value is required and can't be empty"] = "You must specify your ID"
locale = en
```

The config above produces a valid array according to zend translate spec, so:

```
$this -> form -> setTranslator(new Zend_Translate($this -> getConfig() -> translation));
```

expected result is that isEmpty errors should now show up as

```
    You must specify your ID
```

However I'm getting no love. No errors and no translation. I'm on Zend 1.11.1 and PHP5.3.5.

Comment: Just a suggestion...Why not try SPA frameworks for client and move to rest (than traditional mvc) using Zend 1x or 2x? Though there are advantages and disadvantages of both but translation is easier and faster with clientside frameworks. Please check Angular or Ember with Zend. If I am not mistaken Apigility also uses angular for client side rendering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the problem is with `english` key in your ini file. Specifically it should not be there, because what you are actually passing to Zend_Translate as a `content` is:

```
    'content' => array(
        'english' => array(
            "emailNotUnique" => 'Your user already exists' ,
            "Value is required and can't be empty" => 'You must specify your ID' 
        )            
    );
```

And it should be:

```
    'content' => array(          
            "emailNotUnique" => 'Your user already exists' ,
            "Value is required and can't be empty" => 'You must specify your ID'             
    );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thankyou, its great to have someone with a fresh eye come in and solve what has stumped your brain. Chalk one up to looking at the problem too long.

Comment: @devians. Happy to help and I know your feeling:-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
content.english["isEmpty"] = "You must specify your ID"
```

Comment: that would probably work now that i've applied the accepted answer. However, for future people, its recommended by zend to use the actual copy since 1.6 since they will be deprecating the constant defined strings like 'isEmpty'

Answer (score 0):

you can user language file(MO) its simple translate in multiple language

when initialize bootstrap at a time initialize selected language